# Magento Paypal Express invoice is missing error

Tags: magento, paypal

Customer getting error when they place order using payapl express checkout

"invoice is missing" and will not process the order.

Please let me know if anybody know solutions for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue while pay with PayPal Express its giving error (invoice id require).

We follow below step to  solve Invoice ID is require (10003 missing parameter) Error in paypal express.

In paypal express checkout we are sending NVP and IPN request.
From NVP response we get `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM` (invoice Number) that should be match with IPN Post request.

By default magento we not pass invoice ID in IPN Post . paypal will match invoice Id with reference with token.So we have pass Invoice ID in IPN method by changing below code.

in NVP.php file at line 245 we change below code.

You can find NVP.php in (app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php).

```
+++++++++
protected $_doExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest = array(
    'TOKEN', 'PAYERID', 'PAYMENTACTION', 'INVNUM', 'AMT', 'CURRENCYCODE', 'IPADDRESS', 'BUTTONSOURCE', 'NOTIFYURL',
    'RETURNFMFDETAILS', 'SUBJECT', 'ITEMAMT', 'SHIPPINGAMT', 'TAXAMT',
);
+++++++++
```